# Filesystem writes seemingly lost

Tags: bash, filesystems, tcpdump

I've been experimenting with tcpdump, and I've found some very bizarre filesystem behavior.  It doesn't look to be a tcpdump problem as I'll explain in a second.

The following command produces no file:

```
tcpdump -w test.pcap
```

Yet this command produces the PCAP file as expected:

```
tcpdump -w - > test.pcap
```

At first I figured that tcpdump must be encountering some error when writing the file that the shell wasn't, so I straced and found that the writes were occurring just fine!

```
open("test.pcap", O_WRONLY|O_CREAT|O_TRUNC, 0666) = 4 
fstat(4, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=0, ...}) = 0 
mmap(NULL, 4096, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7ff9bf5cb000
rt_sigaction(SIGUSR1, {0x4557d0, [], SA_RESTORER, 0x7ff9bea2ab60}, {SIG_DFL, [], 0}, 8) = 0 
write(2, "tcpdump: ", 9tcpdump: )                = 9 
write(2, "listening on eth0, link-type EN1"..., 73listening on eth0, link-type EN10MB (Ethernet), capture size 65535 bytes) = 73
poll([{fd=3, events=POLLIN}], 1, 1000)  = 1 ([{fd=3, revents=POLLIN}])
poll([{fd=3, events=POLLIN}], 1, 1000)  = 1 ([{fd=3, revents=POLLIN}])
poll([{fd=3, events=POLLIN}], 1, 1000)  = 1 ([{fd=3, revents=POLLIN}])
write(4, "\324\303\262\241\2\0\4\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\377\377\0\0\1\0\0\0001\2\210P\34\3\3\0"..., 4096) = 4096
poll([{fd=3, events=POLLIN}], 1, 1000)  = 1 ([{fd=3, revents=POLLIN}])
poll([{fd=3, events=POLLIN}], 1, 1000)  = 1 ([{fd=3, revents=POLLIN}])
write(4, "\232\241\4\17X\213\f9+\225\35\t\364QF\223\242\7\217Y\226\373l\231vQ\354\223\250i\336."..., 4096) = 4096
poll([{fd=3, events=POLLIN}], 1, 1000)  = 1 ([{fd=3, revents=POLLIN}])
poll([{fd=3, events=POLLIN}], 1, 1000)  = 1 ([{fd=3, revents=POLLIN}])
write(4, "\34\226\346%\354\210\342\331\377\373\222d\261\0\5\207wX\6i`\0U\260\350\260\300\250\0\16\335\241"..., 4096) = 4096
```

test.pcap gets opened as file descriptor 4, and then several writes occur to that descriptor with the syscall reporting that the requested number of bytes was in fact written.

Even so, no file is created.  I scoured the filesystem for test.pcap and found nothing.

What could produce this behavior?

```
tcpdump version 4.3.0
libpcap version 1.3.0
GNU bash, version 4.2.37(1)-release (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu)
Linux persephone 3.4.9-gentoo #1 SMP Wed Oct 3 10:02:39 EDT 2012 x86_64 Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5645 @ 2.40GHz GenuineIntel GNU/Linux
```

Comment: Q: "What could produce this behavior?" A: "A bug or broken hardware". That probably wasn't useful. But, you need to tell us the basic system details for us to have any hope of being useful. Like, say, what filesystem is this?

Comment: Are you sure you're looking in the right directory? Might `tcpdump`'s current directory be in some weird state, like shadowed by a mount?

Comment: @derobert I tried to include all the relevant info; of course I'd forget the filesystem.  It's JFS.

Comment: @Gilles I searched the whole filesystem for the pcap file to no avail.  The shadowing idea is interesting, but nothing is being mounted in the meantime.

Comment: @MichaelShick Can you reproduce this? Even if you run `tcpdump` in a different directory?

Comment: @Gilles yep; it's reproducible consistently both in my JFS home mount and in the ext4 root mount.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`tcpdump` is doing something else to the file. You don't say what the full command-line is; perhaps you have a `-G` in there.

Possible ways to investigate further:-

1. Keep looking through the strace output: maybe you'll find a rename or unlink.
2. While tcpdump is running, run `ln test.pcap pin.test.pcap` and you'll be able to tell if the file was unlinked later.
3. While tcpdump is running, find its process ID and `ls -l /proc/${pid}/fd` to see if you can spot the link to the open file's full pathname. (**This is the approach that actually worked, from @Gilles' comment.**)

Comment: I did post the full command line in both cases; no extra arguments to worry about.  Nothing but write()s to the descriptor.  No close(), but I can't imagine that's it.  Finally I like the link idea, but it fails because the file doesn't exist at any point.

Comment: @MichaelShick What does `ls -l /proc/12345/fd` show while `tcpdump` is running, where 12345 is the PID of `tcpdump`?

Comment: @Gilles That's it!  `4 -> /var/lib/tcpdump/test.pcap`  I guess `updatedb && locate 'test.pcap'` didn't pick up on it.  Also thanks for a new trick for my Linux diagnosis arsenal!

Comment: @MichaelShick for future reference, the best way to search the *entire* filesystem is with `find`. Many locate implementations hide files which aren't visible to all users.

Comment: @derobert normally I do use find, it was a clumsy oversight on my part.  That locate behavior makes a lot of sense, actually.  Thanks.